# How to do conditional decoding of string in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am working on an API call that gets me back the latest revision number, it will generate either UUID(`4e2cab57b35a098993cbaec2455add`) or a date formatted string line (`2023-03-23T04%253a38%253a09Z`).

I would have to apply decode logic to the revision number only when it is generated in date format but not in UUID format and the conversion would be lo `2023-03-23T04%253a38%253a09Z` to `2023-03-23T04:38:09Z`

Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: `converted=${original//%253a/:}`

Comment: `converted=$(perl -pe 's/%25(..)/chr hex $1/ge' <<< "$original")`

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ Please show what you've tried. (From the limited info given, you should be able to just apply jhnc's `converted=${original//%253a/:}` without testing, as that substring should never occur in the UUID form.)

Comment: Decoding the UUID would return the string unchanged; there's no need to do anything conditional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to limit yourself to `bash`-only, you might want to consider using `sed` or `awk`. Both tools already support conditional replacements, but you could use the `case` statement in your shell, if you need to perform additional actions conditionally.

```
revision=....

case "$revision" in
  *-*T*Z) # perform date conversion
    revision="$(printf '%s' "$revision" | sed 's/%253a//g')"
    ;;
  *) # handle everything else, e.g. UUIDs
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried below command and it worked for me

```
echo ${var//substring to be replaced/$replace value}
```